# Angular 4 using nested *ngFor correctly

Tags: angular, checkbox, ngfor, angular4-forms

I am implementing an update webservice. For that I am fetching data from database and populating the form fields with it. The user then needs to edit the data and submit it to update the database.

I need help implementing this with checkboxes. I am trying to use nested *ngFor to fetch 2 different webservices. "maintainanceTypeList" contains all the checkbox options and "defaultmaintainance" contains the options that were checked when user submitted the create form. As you can see I am trying to compare the id of the two and check the checkbox when the comparison returns true.

My problem is that iterations of the nested loops now depend on how many objects my defaultmaintainance has which means same checkboxes are displayed multiple times.

```html
<label for="maintenancetype"
       class="text-3ab08b text-transform"
       style="margin-right: 1em;">
    Maintenance Type:
</label>
<span *ngFor="let x of maintainanceTypeList">
    <span *ngFor="let y of defaultmaintainance">
        <md-checkbox *ngIf="x.isDeleted == 0" 
                     name="{{x.maintenancetype}}" 
                     [checked]="x._id == y._id"
                     (change)="changeMaintainance($event.checked, x)" 
                     value="{{x.maintenancetype}}">
            {{x.maintenancetype}}
        </md-checkbox>
    </span>
</span>
```

edit: Both the arrays are array of objects with multiple objects in this format:

```html
isDeleted:"0"
maintenancetype:"Fixed"
status:"1"
_id:"5971da2c958ccd42a9c99f54"
```

Comment: No. I need to access two completely different arrays.

Comment: Retracted. Can you also please post what `maintainanceTypeList` and `defaultmaintainance` look like?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Ah so `maintainanceTypeList` and `defaultmaintainance` are the same type?

Comment: Yes. Basically I want to compare the id of the two and when they are the same I want the checkbox to be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would modify `maintainanceTypeList` adding to each it's item an additional property which shows should this item be checked or not:

```js
let selectedIds = defaultmaintainance.map(item => item._id);

maintainanceTypeList.forEach(checkbox => {
    checkbox.checked = (selectedIds.indexOf(checkbox._id) > -1) ? true : false;
})
```

And then display `maintainanceTypeList` within a single *ngFor loop:

```html
<span *ngFor="let x of maintainanceTypeList">
    <md-checkbox *ngIf="x.isDeleted == 0" 
                 name="{{x.maintenancetype}}" 
                 [checked]="x.checked"
                 (change)="changeMaintainance($event.checked, x)" 
                 value="{{x.maintenancetype}}">
        {{x.maintenancetype}}
    </md-checkbox>
</span>
```